# Data accessing & display in Django

Tags: django, database

- I'm having trouble accessing database data in another template
  different than django administration. In the administration page I
  get results:

[image]

- But when I try to display them in another template:

[image] (No results available)

- Here's how my *urls.py* admin page and template urls looks like:

  ```
  urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('lista/', views.entitats, name = 'lista_entitats')
  ]
  ```
- Here's how my *admin.py* call to entity list and register looks like:

  ```
  class EntitatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('codi', 'nom', 'adreça', 'cp', 'correu', 'inspector')
      inlines = [DiaLliureDisposicioInline, VisitesDirectorCentreInline, ExitEscolarInline, ObresCentreInline, OfertaEstudisInline, NEE_alumnatInline, FormacioInline, ProjectesInline, ProfessorsInline, DespesesFuncionamentInline]
      search_fields=('nom',)
      list_per_page=5

  admin.site.register(Entitat, EntitatAdmin)
  ```
- In my *views.py* this is how I ask for the template (and where I feel I'm not getting db information well):

  ```
  from entitats.models import Entitat

  def entitats(request):
      lista_entitats = Entitat.objects.all()
      context = {'llista_entitats': lista_entitats}
      return render(request, 'entitats.html', context)
  ```
- And finally my template, where I try to display the list of entities:

  ```
  {% if context.llista_entitats %}
      <ul>
          {% for question in objects_list %}
              <li><a href="/admin/entitats/entitat/{{ entitat.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
  {% else %}
      <p>Ninguna entidad disponible.</p>
  {% endif %}
  ```

Sorry if it's loong, I'll delete if there's something not necessary, and THANKYOU in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `context.variable_name` syntax in template to check variable value, just use:

```
{% if llista_entitats %}
```

instead of

```
{% if context.llista_entitats %}
```

Also since your variable is `llista_entitats` it should be:

```
{% for question in llista_entitats %}
    <li><a href="/admin/entitats/entitat/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note I replaced `objects_list` with `llista_entitats` and  `entitat.id` with `question.id`.

Comment: OMG a day with this and it was just a type error... THANKYOU!